# Finding (and booking) accomodation in ireland

Tags: online-resources, accommodation, ireland

I am planning a road trip in Ireland (mostly in the republic) and I wonder how to find (and book) accommodations. I am looking for B&B, since hotels looks quite expensive there

- Booking.com, seems to have a lot of offers (which also appears in other websites like [bedandbreakfast.eu](https://bedandbreakfast.eu)
- the [www.bandbireland.com](https://www.bandbireland.com) website
- The local tourism board websites ([example](https://purecork.ie/stay/categories/bb)) list various type of accommodation,
- AirBnB

I am missing something ? Is there a best way to find a good (and not too expensive) place ? And how difficult/expensive is it to book something at the last minute in the summer ?

Comment: There is a housing crisis in Ireland at the time of posting this comment and this has led to some places that accomodate tourists being used as temporary accomodation for those who would otherwise be homeless.  So you may need to compromise your goals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have found most options to select from a site, I would add a search with the name of the place and B&B, and that should show up all B&B's which do not like to join one of the bigger booking sites but still allow online or telephone bookings.

When I traveled Ireland I did so by train and bus, which did not allow for much flexibility in changing locations if you find everything booked solid.
With a car you are more flexible, you might find the nearest place with a room for you is half an hour driving away. Or you may find what a friend on a motorcycle with problems found, the only place he could reach was a posh (4 star?) manor house hotel.

So it is up to your risk avoidance or risk taking, I would not travel in summer without reservations but I do not even travel outside the summer without reservations. Ireland is quite popular and can at times be very busy with tourists, weekends round the year can already book out all B&B's in the more popular places, in summer I fear it can be impossible to find anything near the popular coast places and Dublin.
But I have not been there in summer.